# Rds RemoteApp logged off immediately after preparing desktop (under details) msi and rdp

Tags: remote-desktop, server, remoteapp

We are working on a remote desktop server 2008 R2 Sp1 that has all the updates. 
Yesterday i wanted to install an office 2013 MAK professional plus next to the allready installed office 2010 standard. For that i had chosen for a custom install and clicked the radio button that told me to leave the previous version (office 2010).

After the installation of the office 2013 the office 2010 became corrupted by a not know reason so what i have done is remove everything of office and just installed the office 2013 (all in install modus -> change user /install).

We had some GPO enabled that had influence on the office 2010 installation and i just turned these of. On the same time i have made some changes in my default GPO to make a shortcut on every remote desktop of all office programs.

Last thing i have done yesterdag was expand the hard drive volume from 100Gb to 250Gb and rebooted that server a last time.

This morning all of the sudden it is not possible anymore to start a remote app (not only the office remote apps but also the ones made before). When we start the remote app the starting screen is just disappearing after a while. When i click on the detail button i see it is loading the GPO's and then gives "preparing desktop" but right after that it is "logging off".

The strangest part about this is that the user can log on with his name on the remote server -> remote desktop without any problems.

How can this be possible? There are toppics i have found over the internet but none of them are answered..

When i take a look at the event viewer i see some errors appearing when someone click on the remote app but i dont know if it has anything to do with that..

```
    A timeout (30000 milliseconds) was reached while waiting for a transaction response from the UmRdpService service.

User Logon Notification for Customer Experience Improvement Program

User Logoff Notification for Customer Experience Improvement Program
```

Hope to find some help here!

Answer (score 3):

Came out that it had nothing to do with my actions yesterday but indead because of an update released yesterday.

Found the exact KB trough the website of serverfault. After removing the Update `KB3004394` and doing a reboot the problem is solved! Just had to exclude this update the next time till there is a fix for this. Special thanks to Gordon who posted this!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to remove this update and reboot the affected server.

A couple of things to note:

1. Immediately upon reboot, same issue remained (oh crap)
2. Decided to remove same KB from guest computer and rebooted
3. Upon reboot, same issue remained
4. While researching issue further, about 10 minutes lapsed and I decided to try it again and it worked.

I can't explain the delay in it working, but I was able to resolve it with just that one KB removal.